# E:The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt tessa-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: android, postgresql, android-studio, wifi, apt

I have installed android studio on my linux mint 19.1 and after installation of it I restarted my PC. After restarting I couldn't see wi-fi sign in my machine.

Enable wifi option is not showing. I opened driver manager and I got the above error. I have already tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. I also restarted my machine several times.

Comment: For the moment, I've just could take the repository out. Go to etc/apt/sources.list.d and there, open file pgdg.list. There should go the propper address. Since I couln't make it work, I've just erase everything in order to update the system till I could find the way.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this error appeared since the PostgreSQL repo doesn't have a release for "tessa".

Two solutions:

1. Edit the "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list" file (or another list file contains "http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt tessa-pgdg Release") and change "tessa" to one of the version name supported by PostgreSQL (here is the list: https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/).
2. Simply delete "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list" or remove the line "http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt tessa-pgdg Release" in other file if you are not using PostgreSQL.

Comment: A little more info about the first option above. When you follow the instructions on the pgadmin site for installing on Ubunut. It generates this file with the name of the distro release you are running, even if there is no supported pgadmin release available. I decided to run it from a docker container instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `focal-pgdg` worked in `Mint Una`

Answer (score 1):

Here $(lsb_release -cs) returns terra and this doesn't work in many distributions. Use bionic instead, it should work

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/bionic pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

And then finally install pgadmin:

```
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

1. make

   /etc/apt
2. make

   sources.list.d
3. make

   rm pgdg.list
4. make

   sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade